# Android Notification intent to clear it self

Tags: android, notifications, android-intent

I have read many examples of how to create notification messages.
What i wanted to achieve, is because the notification will be executed by a widget, i would like
the notification intent when clicked to clear it self when the user clicks on it.I do not have an activity to return to.
The notification for my purposes will just plainly notify, nothing else.
So what would be the code of an intent that just clear/cancel itself.
The code below is an activity launched by a button(button code not included) the notification will be fired up by a background service.

```
CharSequence title = "Hello";
CharSequence message = "Hello, Android!";
final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
final Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,"A New Message!",System.currentTimeMillis());

notification.defaults=Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE+Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, AndroidNotifications.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,notificationIntent, 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(AndroidNotifications.this, title,message, pendingIntent);
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 74):

Check out [FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL)

Bit to be bitwise-ored into the flags field that should be set if the notification should be canceled when it is clicked by the user.

**EDIT :**

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Comment: My code is already using FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL but actually the notification is not going away on click.

Comment: Your code uses wrong (puts in defaults field), you need to bitwise-or in the flags field like this:  `notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;`

Comment: Thanks notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL; Worked.

Comment: Flag doesn't seem to be working here. Further setting this flag causes continuously playing notification sound

Answer (score 19):

Set the flags in notification.flags instead of notification.defaults.

Example:

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Answer (score 10):

If you're using `NotificationCompat.Builder` (a part of `android.support.v4`) then simply call its object's method `setAutoCancel`

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
builder.setAutoCancel(true);
```

Some guys were reporting that `setAutoCancel()` did not work for them, so you may try this way as well

```
builder.build().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Comment: it seems that using actions (with addAction() ) doesn't auto-cancel the notification

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see of doing this is to have your `Notification`'s `Intent` point to a background `Service`. When this Service is launched, it would clear the given `Notification` using `NotificationManager.cancel(int id)`. The `Service` would then stop itself. It's not pretty, and would not be easy to implement, but I can't find any other way of doing it.

Comment: If you want by code to cancel the notification use the `NOTIFICATION_ID` on cancel call.

Comment: Yes i would be calling that from a button, but i would like to call that from the code when the user selects the notification.

Comment: Works-for-me solution, however a bit messy (additional service to be written). But in Service I have access to calling Intent in which the notification ID as argument can be given.

Answer (score 1):

```
 /** 
      Post a notification to be shown in the status bar. 
      Obs.: You must save this values somewhere or even pass it as an extra through Intent to use it later
 */
 notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

 /** 
      Cancel a previously shown notification given the notification id you've saved before
 */
 notificationmanager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

Comment: cancelling the notification right after `notify()` causes the notification is not being displayed at all.

Answer (score 1):

Using setContentIntent should solve your problem:

```
.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
```

For example:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder= new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle("title")
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentText("content")
        .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Often you might want to direct the user to the relevant content and so might replace 'new Intent()' with something else.