# Cancelled Notification being redelivered when other notification is touched. Android

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-notifications, notificationmanager

I am having an issue where, no matter what notification the user touches, I am always receiving the same notification, even though it is cancelled.

The first notification a user touches is the only notification that will ever be delivered to my pending intent, until device reboot (then the first touched notification becomes the new Hotel California notification).
[image: notification tray]

Here is how I am constructing the notifications:

```
    final Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    final int notificationId = Integer.parseInt(payload.getObjectId());

    extras.putInt(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationId);

    final Intent intent = new Intent(context,
            PushNotificationLauncherActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    intent.putExtras(extras);

    final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context);
    builder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name));
    builder.setContentText(payload.getText());
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_launcher);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);

    final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            intent, 0, extras);

    builder.setContentIntent(pIntent);

    final Notification notification;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        notification = builder.getNotification();
    } else {
        notification = builder.build();
    }

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
```

Then I have this in my `PushNotificationLauncherActivity`:

```
    final Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    final int notificationId = extras
            .getInt(SocialcastGoogleCloudMessageReceiver.NOTIFICATION_ID);

    final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // please go away
    notificationManager.cancel(notificationId);

    Log.d(PushNotificationLauncherActivity.class.getSimpleName(),
            "Touched notification ID: " + String.valueOf(notificationId));
```

No matter which notification I touch, in the log `Touched notification ID: 1234` will always show, even if the notification I touch on has an ID of `56789`.

I highly doubt it is an issue with my test-device, but incase it helps; I am using a 2013 Nexus 7 with KitKat 4.4.4 with the Dalvik runtime (not ART) Build KTU84P.

Comment: This is different from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479428/android-notification-intent-to-clear-it-self in that, my notification does go away. The problem is when a new notification is added, the receiver gets the first zombie notification again. #notadupe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass your `notificationId` as the `request code` here:

```
final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
        intent, 0, extras);
```

Change this to:

```
final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notificationId,
        intent, 0, extras);
```

When comparing two `Intent` instances, the included `Bundles` are not compared. So, from android's point of view, the two intents are the same.

Interestingly, the `reqCode` (second argument in `PendingIntent.getActivity(...)`) *is* compared. And this should render your `Intents` unique.

Comment: Interesting, I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: @BlakeBarrett Ahh yes. The documentation is really misleading on this issue. I am glad this helped. I remember having a hard time figuring this out myself.